# How create loop tween?

Tags: dart, stagexl

I'm using stagexl (on dart lang) for my game. I tried find in api how restart tween after it will be complete, but could not. Can you help me? Thnx.

Comment: You must show us what you tried and how and where your blocked ***precisely***. Difficult to help you otherwise. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking your next question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not restart a Tween, you have to create a new one. You could also use the new async methods like juggler.onElapsedTimeChange, juggler.interval or juggler.timespan. Or you could implement your own tween-like class which implements the Animatable interface.

Here is an example for the juggler.interval method:

```
await for (var counter in juggler.interval(delay).take(666)) {
  // do something 666 times.
}
```

Here is an example for juggler.onElapsedTimeChange

```
await for (var time in juggler.onElapsedTimeChange) {
  // do something with time.
}
```

Here is an exmaple for the Animatable interface

```
class MyAnimation implements Animatable {
  bool advanceTime(num time) {
    // do something with time
    return true; // animation should continue on next frame
  }
}
```

Please check out the Juggler documentation:
http://www.stagexl.org/docs/wiki-articles.html?article=juggler